# Cant connect to DB. Won't Stop Loading

Tags: php, database, mysqli, xampp

I cant figure out why i am not connecting to my db. It seems like it is finding the host but having authentication problems or something. I am using xampp and the db provided with it. My connect code is as follows

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost:1234';
$username = 'protech';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'protech';
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    echo "Connected successfully";
}

    mysqli_close($conn);
    exit;
?>
```

if you need any information I am by my computer and will respond quick.

I get these error messages after waiting a while.

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\protech_connect.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=7764 in C:\xampp\htdocs\protech_connect.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\protech_connect.php on line 9

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\protech_connect.php on line 9

Comment: are you running on a non-standard port? if so, remove the port from the host and append as a fifth parameter to the mysqli_connect. Preferably use an OO approach

Comment: Please provide the error message you see

Comment: @RamRaider i tried that code that was provided and still did not work. Stephen Reindl It just keeps loading it wont give an error

Comment: is this on your local dev machine or on live host? Is password genuinely empty? check your php error logs to see what is happening. Also, is the mysql server set to listen on port 1234?

Comment: check my post edit in 1 minute

Comment: ok it seems to be working now that i use port 3306 i was using my apache port. thanks for the help im going to try to insert somthing and see if it works

Answer (score 2):

The standard port for mySQL is 3306 - so if you are genuinely using 1234 then append that as a new parameter to the db connection constructor.

```
    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'protech'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'protech';
    $dbport =    1234;
    $conn   =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname, $dbport );

    if( $conn->connect_error ) exit( 'Bad foo: '.$conn->connect_error );
    else { /* do exciting things */ }

    $conn->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `mysqli_connect()` function doesn't accept a port in the host parameter. You need to add the port number in another parameter like so:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $serverport);
```

Function documentation: [`mysqli::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: i did that it still keeps just loading

Answer (score 1):

If you get following error or problem then follow above solution.

**Error:**
Warning:  mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away
Warning:  mysqli_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=3528
Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away

**Solution 1:**
use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Don't use any port number after 127.0.0.1.

**Solution 2:**
Check your host file located at
**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc**
and remove any localhost or 127.0.0.1 entry in file and save.
 You can use any HostEditor program to edit this file.